# Can WinForm app that's running on .net framework 3.5 reference to a Class library that's on a .net framework 4.5 (all in the same solution)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, frameworks

I have WinForm app that's running on .NET Framework 3.5.

I added a new C# Class Library that's on .NET Framework 4.5 (in the same solution, because one of my NuGet requires .NET Framework 4.5).

When I reference that Class Library from *MainForm.cs* and Rebuild solution I got an error saying that *MainForm/bin/debug/dll* is missing.

Is it possible to do that in VS2019.

I was reading
[visual-studio-multi-targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019)

> Visual Studio solution can contain projects that target different
> versions of .NET. However, note that you can **only build against a
> single version** of .NET either using reference conditionals for a
> single build or recursively build different binaries for each
> version...

*This is edited part:*

Try this...

1. Create new Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) Project. Select .NET Framework 3.5
2. In the solution explorer window
   right click on solution -> add -> new project

- and select C# Class Library (.NET Framework) .dll
- chose .NET Framework 4.5

3. Next - right click on main form References -> Add Reference -> Projects

- and check your Class Library

4. Add label to main form
5. Go to Class Library code and add

```
        public static string hello = "Hello from class library";
```

6. Go to the main form code add statement

```
        using ClassLibrary1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = Class1.hello;
        }
```

7. Click

- Build -> Clean Solution
- Build -> Rebuild Solution

Output window displays following:

Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: netFW35andNetFW45, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "D:\testNet35andNet45\netFW35andNetFW45\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "D:\testNet35andNet45\netFW35andNetFW45\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
1>D:\testNet35andNet45\netFW35andNetFW45\netFW35andNetFW45\Form1.cs(9,7,9,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

*How to display text from ClassLibrary1 in label1.text ?*
**Thank you**

Comment: Older versions of Net required multiple versions of Net to be installed on Machine like : Net 1.-, Net 2.0, Net 3.0, Net 3.5, Net 4.0.  New versions of Net only the latest version need to be installed.  Projects have bin/debug and bin/release versions. Your dll may be in the release folder instead of the debug folder.  Deploy means that you are targeting older versions of Net than the one installed so that code built with older versions will still compile with current version. You have a missing dll and using different version of net will not solve issue.  Try using release version or rebuild.

Comment: Your missing dll may have occurred due to the build not completing due to errors which may be fixed by changing versions of Net.

Comment: Hey @jdweng please read my edit... thank you for your answers

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  Not sure why your are getting the error about Net 2.0.  Some place you are targeting Net 2.0.

Comment: Do you mean step #7 Build -> Clean Solution - Build -> Rebuild Solution?

Comment: Would you try to see what will you get in Output and Error window ?

Comment: Clean build everything instead of just what changed from last build. I would expect not to see ""2.0.0.0" in the current target framework".

Comment: There is no way to get that work. Windows forms app needs to be .net framework 4.5 to use a .net framework 4.5 class library. Thank you for your support

Comment: The version of Net that software was built needs to be on the deployed machine.  With Net you can target older version of Net.  If you have Net 4.8 installed you  can still target Net 4.5.